# NodeJS - custom modules - unable to invoke my custom module

Tags: node.js, express, module

I'm trying out some code snipped from the web to understand working of custom nodes.
Here's the code that I'm trying to execute :

```
/**
* mymodule.js Created by vinod on 4/13/2015.
*/

var exports = module.exports = {};
var myfunct = function()
{
    console.log("Just used myfunct()... ");
}

exports = myfunct;

/**
 * testclient.js Created by vinod on 4/13/2015.
 */

var extMod = require('./mymodule.js')
extMod.myfunct();
```

This is throwing the below error :

```
extMod.myfunct();
   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (d:\nodews\learnyounode\testjs\testclient.js:7:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Appreciate your help in knowing why this is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your have 2 mistakes in your code. The first one is about what references what at which time.

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
```

After this line both `module.exports` and your local `exports` reference the same (empty) object. everything is fine.

```
var myfunct = function() {
    console.log("Just used myfunct()... ");
}
```

Now you define a function - no problems here.

```
 exports = myfunct;
```

Now you change, what `exports` refers to. `export` now references the function you just created. `module.exports`, however, never got changed and hence still points to the empty object from the start. So you are actually exporting just the empty object in this module.

The second problem with your code is about what you export. So to fix your module, we could just replace this

```
 exports = myfunct;
```

by this

```
 module.exports = myfunct;
```

ans it will work.

If you have a close look now, you'll see, that you just export the function itself. After including it in the other module via

```
var extMod = require('./mymodule.js')
```

you will just have the function and not an object, where this function is a property. So you could just call it via

```
extMod();
```

---

The other solution would be, to adjust your first module to the call of the second one. For this we need to make `myfunct` a property of the resulting object:

```
module.exports.myfunct = myfunct;
```

Now the call in the second module should work. This is because we did not replace the the empty object in the export, but just augment it with a new property, whose value is the formerly defined function.

One interesting point, you can see from this later example is, that the function you define, the name under which you export it and the name under which you use it, do not necessarily have to be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much Sirko. this helped and worked. Appreciate your detailed explanation.